# passing HashMap from mapper to reducer directly

Tags: hadoop, hashmap, mapreduce

I am very new to Hadoop and working on map-reduce on train data.
I used HashMap to collect some summary of each mapper in the mapping phase.
Now I want this HashMap to be used by the Reducer for some type of output.

The other data created by each mapper is sent to reducer by Context.write() method. But I cannot mix-up the two type of data.

```
public class ExcelMapper
extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {  
Map<Text, Text> map1 = new HashMap<Text, Text>();//collects some 
                                                   //summarised 
                                                  //data from each mapper
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
  throws InterruptedException, IOException {......}}





public class ExcelReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

Map<Text, Text> map3 = new HashMap<Text, Text>();

ExcelMapper m1 = new ExcelMapper();

m1.map1.putAll(map3); //map3 is empty.

public void reduce(Text outputkey, Iterable<Text> outputvalue,
  Context context) throws InterruptedException, IOException {...}}
```

map3 should show the copied data from m1.map1 but it shows empty.

Comment: This isn't possible. I'm not sure what you're trying to do by instantiating the Mapper within the Reducer.

Comment: I think it's possible with the serialization of the object in mapper and deserialization of it in the reducer. Actually, mapper and reducer run in different JVMs. And that is causing the problem. Can you tell me how to serialize and deserialize objects in mapreduce?

Comment: The above code was just to explain my problem.

Comment: That's not really how this works... You can have many instances of Mappers and Reducers, so how would a Reducer know which map to work with? Data is serialised between Mappers and Reducers, you're effectively asking how to run two separate MR jobs in the same job, which isn't possible.